# Is there a good GUI for Azure Cosmos for visualisation and editing?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am looking for any type of GUI for graph visualization and editing of my cosmos gremlin graph.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, if my answer helps you,you could mark it.

Comment: @JayGong - Unfortunately this particular question is off-topic (and already closed), as it's a tool/product/service recommendation question. There's really no "right" answer for such a question. And promoting commercial solutions really doesn't fit (and there have been many cases where such answers has been deemed spam, due to promotion of various products and services, as answers).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute query sql or view the structure of your data,you could use Azure Cosmos Db portal or Cosmos db Extension in VS Code.

[image]

If you want to implement more features,please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-visualization) to try below tools which are not for free:

- Linkurious Enterprise
- Cambridge Intelligence